# MVVM and modality in portable view models

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, modal-dialog, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

My app (written using MvvmCross and with MVVM pattern in mind) needs to display popup windows where user can choose of confirm certain options. So basically it's a classic modal dialog, but since the app's view model is implemented in a portable class library, it needs to tackle modality in a generalized sense - some platforms simply don't have exact match for a modal dialog.

There are a few threads discussing dialogs in MVVM ([Open dialog in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805778/open-dialog-in-wpf-mvvm), [WPF MVVM dialog example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667888/wpf-mvvm-dialog-example)). Following their advices I could probably solve this by introducing DialogService and implementing it for each platform. However I will be treating then dialogs like other services - storage service, map service etc.. But a dialog is a part of the presentation concept, so I wonder if it can be treated more like a view, so instead of calling an instance of an obscure IDialogService I could navigate to it using an MVVM framework of my choice (MvvmCross in my case).

I checked MvvmCross implementation and samples but found almost no dialog-related stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within MvvmCross, the `presenter` is responsible for how Views/ViewModels are shown when using `ShowViewModel`.

This presenter is a view/UI level object - it's ultimately the UIs job to decide if a view should be shown as a page, as a control, in a tab, in a split-view, as a dialog, etc.

v3 does introduce a presentation hint that the ViewModel can help suggest how the View should be shown - but it's up to the presenter on each platform to determine how (if) to use this hint.

---

Alternatively, Dialogs/flyouts/etc can easily be shown using MvxMessenger messages from ViewModel to View with a little bit of code behind.

---

For 'modality', also consider Greg's post on 'returning results' - see http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/11/returning-results-from-view-models-in-mvvmcross/

Comment: I see. I looked at IMvxMessenger, it has a clear pub/sub shape, so I wonder if this is correct to use it to implement "edit details" functionality. Even if it fits technically, is it correct design-wise?
Coming back to presenter, I assume I will need to register a custom implementation of IMvxViewDispatcher that will do the presenter's job. But I will need to plug it somewhere in so it will fire a dialog. Are there any samples with similar functionality?
(and of course thank you for a quick response, as usual).

Comment: I don't look for 'design-wise' perfection - I look for something that works, then refactor it towards something clean, reusable, beautiful. Greg's post is nice for 'edit details' functionality. Also check out custom presenters in: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Setup.cs, https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Touch, https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch - they all build customised architecture in the UI app

Comment: The Touch platform also includes a built-in modal presenter using a marker-interface based hint - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I am also not looking for design perfection, but it helps get orientated about acceptable paths to avoid getting lost in code mess. The links you gave me seems to help a lot to understand how to quickly come with working and maintainable solution. Thanks again!