# How to create and show popups from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, viewmodel

First of I should apologize if the question seems to look simple however I'm new to WPF and MVVM and I really don't know how to do the job.

What I need is to show popups from ViewModel. I know I can have a boolean property in the viewModel and bind it to the `IsOpen` property of the Popup but I don't know where to create this popup window.

I have some views and each view has to display certain popup messages depending on different situations. Now I need to know whether I should create several popups in each view and bind their `IsOpen` property to that of in the ViewModel or there are better solutions, and if I should create them in the view, where to put them? In a grid, in a `StackPanel` or anywhere else.

please let me know if I haven't explained clearly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is sample popup. [reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-popup/)

[basic popup msdn overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<StackPanel>
<CheckBox Name="PCheckBox" Margin="10,10,0,0"
      Content="Popup Window"/>
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="129" Margin="10,10,0,0">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="theTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    Start Animation
</Button>
<Popup  IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PCheckBox,Path=IsChecked}"
   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PCheckBox}"           
   AllowsTransparency="True"
   PopupAnimation="Slide"
   HorizontalOffset="150"
   VerticalOffset="100"
   >

    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Green" Margin="150">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="theTransform" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="LightGray">
  Rotating Popup
</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Popup>
```

```
 private void OnPopupLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - gdChild.ActualWidth) / 2;
        this.ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - gdChild.ActualHeight) / 2;
    }
```

Comment: Great. and how should I show it in the center of the screen please?

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a Third object to control my popup's and dialog , like Caliburn's WindowManager

[WindowManager](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/)

Witch takes a ViewModel as Content and Displays it's Corresponding View in the Popup.

You can do something similar and Bind a Content from your ViewModel to your popup or Dialog.

For Instance , here's an a Custom Action i created for such a purpose :

[OpenPopupWindowAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596168/prism-popupchildwindowaction-in-desktop-dll-missing/18596368#18596368)