# Change WPF DataGrid Cell Font based on comparison of cell values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to using the WPF DataGrid and I'm kind of lost. What I have is a DataTable with numeric values to which I bind the DataGrid via a DataView. What I want to do is compare the values of each column, and make the cell that has the bigger value per column, bold. (e.g. Who wins in each category)

There's no ObservableCollection, no fancy stuff. I'm just adding data to a DataTable the "manual" way, getting the values cell-by-cell from an SQLite database DataTable response. Even the columns are created programatically, and not via XAML. I have almost no experience in XAML, so don't assume I've worked with Triggers or anything.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from small examples. You can create some test data, with which you can try data binding technique. Try to style some parts of `DataGrid`: change colors of `Foreground`, add some `Border` with `BorderBrush`. Explore WPF yourself - it is hard only for the first view.

Here is some how to:

- [Use converters in WPF](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters)
- [Use binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)
- [Use styles and templates for DataGrid elements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx)
- [Use MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662309/good-examples-of-mvvm-template)